# How can I get all my questions for a specific tag?

Tags: support, search, tag-search

I ask a lot of questions and would like to just see all my questions which contain a certain tag, for example [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios). Is this possible? How would I do it (easily)?

Comment: Click on the particular tag under the __Tags__ section on your profile page.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [Search Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching), it's quite a useful tool if you know how to work your way around it: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A152825+is%3Aq+%5Bios%5D

Comment: thx Mike - looks good

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following in the search field:

```
user:me is:question [ios]
```

This will give you posts that meet all of the following conditions:

- You wrote them: `user:me`.
- They are questions: `is:question`.
- They have the [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) tag: `[ios]`.

Comment: Of course this works for **answers** as well. E.g. `user:2411320 [apache-spark] is:answer`. Thank green Squrtle!